# trying to recursively search for files with a certain word in their file name using CMD (windows)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a script that will search for all file recursively in a folder and run a command and/or list of commands on each file. Here's an example of how I need it to work:

- Search folder for files containing "1080p" in the file name
- Copy this file to a local directory *but* remove the "1080p" from the filename
- Run another batch script on those files (I already have that part working)

All this needs to be automated.

I need to do this in the Windows command prompt and I'm willing to use any other programs required.
I'm already using SED in a similar batch script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "src=sourcePath"
set "dst=destinationPath"
set "search=1080p"

for /r "%src%" %%F in (*%search%*) do (
  set "full=%%~fF"
  set "name=%%~nxF"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    copy "!full!" "%dst%\!name:%search%=!"
    endlocal
)
REM call your batch script here to process the copied files
```

You could have problems if the same filename exists in multiple source folders. But that is a general problem with your stated requirements.

***Explanation:***

`%%~fF` gives the full path to the file contained in %%F

`$$~nxF` gives the name and extension only of the file contained in %%F

type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` for more information about the modifiers available for FOR variable expansion.

`!name:%search%=!` uses delayed expansion to search the contents of name and replace the search value with nothing. In this example %search%=1080p. Note that the search is not case sensitive.

I need to use delayed expansion when doing search and replace within the loop because normal expansion using percents occurs when the statement is parsed. But the entire FOR construct, encluding the contents of the parentheses, is parsed as one logical statement. So normal expansion would give the value of name prior to the loop executing. That won't work :-) Delayed expansion gives the current value each time the line is executed.

Type `HELP SET` or `SET /?` for more information about search and replace and delayed expansion.

I need to toggle delayed expansion on and off because `!` is a valid character in a filename, and %%F expansion will corrupt the value if it contains `!`.

Comment: thanks! this did exactly what i needed it to do! any chance you can explain what some parts of the command do? i understand what's going on up to "  set "full=%%~fF"  ". i'd love to understand what %%~fF and  %%~nxF do. also this !full!" "%dst%\!name:%search%=!.

Comment: Nice! Three questions: (1) Why do you `setlocal disableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning? It's the default, isn't it? (2) Why do you re-enable it just-in-time instead of up front? Isn't specifiying either `%foo%` or `!foo!` enough to distinguish between both? (3) Why do you use `SET` with the quotes around the variable names as well? - Thanks! - @KostaV. : Take a look at `FOR /?`, `CALL /?` and `SET /?` for some revelations! With `cmd.exe`, the docs are well hidden! Also check out [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html).

Comment: @Lumi - 1) It is the default under most circumstances, but it can't hurt to be explicit, especially when the method requires that it start off disabled. 2) Read the explanation that I recently added 3) The quote pattern I used protects special characters like `&` and `^` without incorporating the quotes in the value. It also guarantees there is nothing in the assignment after the last quote.

Comment: great! i have a slightly better understanding about how this works. thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: To only search for your keyword within the extension names of your files modify the Set condition to this - (\*.*%search%\*)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using cygwin to easily take advantage of some common Unix utilities, although you can probably locate windows compiled versions one by one (i.e. perl):

**Find a list of files by name, execute a command on each:**

```
find . -name \*1080p\* | xargs <command>
```

**Find a list of files, create a list of move/rename commands to strip out '1080p' string:**

```
find . -name \*1080p\* | perl -ne 'chomp();$x=$_;s/1080p//g;print"cp $x /target/$_\n"'
# add "| sh" to run the commands, or "> commands.sh" to generate a script
```

**Command that should run in CMD only requiring PERL**

```
dir /s /b | perl -ne 'chomp();$x=$_;s/1080p//g;print"copy $x c:\target\$_\n"' > cmds.bat
```

Adjust the scripts, of course, to do what you need.  However, I believe this will accomplish your goal.  There may be a clever way to do this with Windows CMD, but I am not a CMD expert.  Unix utilities are (IMHO) much more straightforward!